# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skpy' " happen even though I already installed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Though I installed skpy by pip and pip3, the error happened when I command `jupyter execute` on the terminal.

`Python 3.9.13 pip 22.2.2 from /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)`

**Proof I installed skpy**

```
(base) username@MacBook-Pro-3 test-directory % pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- --------------------
・・・
SkPy                          0.10.4
・・・
・・・
```

```
(base) username@MacBook-Pro-3 test-directory % pip3 install skpy
Requirement already satisfied: skpy in /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.10.4)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from skpy) (4.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from skpy) (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->skpy) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->skpy) (2022.9.24)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->skpy) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->skpy) (1.26.11)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->skpy) (3.3)
```

**Execution command**

```
(base) username@MacBook-Pro-3 test-directory % /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/jupyter execute /Users/username/Desktop/job/test-directory/createNewShiftTab.ipynb
```

**The error after run above command**

```
[NbClientApp] Executing /Users/username/Desktop/job/test-directory/createNewShiftTab.ipynb
[NbClientApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/jupyter-execute", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 276, in launch_instance
    return super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 981, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 110, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/cli.py", line 113, in initialize
    [self.run_notebook(path) for path in self.notebooks]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/cli.py", line 113, in <listcomp>
    [self.run_notebook(path) for path in self.notebooks]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/cli.py", line 154, in run_notebook
    client.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 85, in wrapped
    return just_run(coro(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 60, in just_run
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 701, in async_execute
    await self.async_execute_cell(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 1019, in async_execute_cell
    await self._check_raise_for_error(cell, cell_index, exec_reply)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 913, in _check_raise_for_error
    raise CellExecutionError.from_cell_and_msg(cell, exec_reply_content)
nbclient.exceptions.CellExecutionError: An error occurred while executing the following cell:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 9
      6 from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
      7 # print(sys.path) importしたモジュールの探索先ディレクトリを一覧表示
      8 #Skype操作
----> 9 from skpy import Skype

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skpy'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skpy'
```

But when I executed on the JupyterLab browser directly, it didn’t happen as below, so I’m confusing.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AI36.png)

**And this is the output of sys.path**

```
['/Users/username/Desktop/job/automation', '/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python39.zip', '/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9', '/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '', '/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aeosa', '/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/Users/username/.ipython']
```

- Run `print(sys.path)` then confirmed the module was in the directory where python searched to use module
- Restart mac, terminal, jupyter
- fix text to "SkPy" from "skpy"

But all of them didn’t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a play off Rubizzo's answer:

A very simple fix here is just installing using the same Python version as your juypter notebook is using.

```bash
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/python -m pip install skpy
```

Should do it.

For further clarification: You seem to have multiple versions of Python installed. If you run

```bash
where python3
```

You will see every Python 3.xx.xx installation you have. The very top one is the version you use if you simply run a command like

```bash
pip install <package>
or
python3 <file>
```

But you can select any of the python versions using their full paths to run a file or to use pip with.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different versions of python3. You installed your package for python 3.9 but Jupyter uses python3.10.
Or you force Jupyter to use python3.9 or you install your package for python3.10 too.